# Looking to automate 2 pool pumps and 1 heater

Tags: smart-home

So this has been asked here a few times before but I was hoping for some additional wiring help.

I have 2 phase 240 VAC connection going to my pool equipment (4 wires) and would like to run the primary pool pump (7 A draw at 230 V), as well as a pool sweep pump (7 A draw at 230 V) and a pool heater (2 A draw at 230 V). The goal is to be able to schedule all 3 separately. In a perfect world they would be conditional (you shouldn't be able to run the pool sweep or heater if main pump isn't on) but I can schedule around this.

For the WiFi piece I was going to use this [Sonoff](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BHWF8KD).

Obviously I wouldn't want to run the pumps directly off this (though the heater should be fine)

So I need help locating the contactors and thinking through the wiring to make this all work...
For contactors I was thinking something along [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019G8OQCY) lines?

Would love some help.

Comment: `I need help locating the contactors` ... shopping questions are off topic

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: Questions are: will my plan work with the listed items? If so can I get help on how to wire the relays

Comment: this site is for answering focused questions ...it is not a tutorial site ... find a tutorial about wiring relays ... ask a question if you run into problems

Comment: are you certain that the heater draws only 2 A?

Comment: Certain on the heater - it’s a gas heater so electrical draw is nominal

Comment: I think this question is more suited for Home Improvement SE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shopping

Comment: It appears that you dont have any concerns with the IoT aspect of the solution you have presented. You have concerns with the electrical aspect. Please ask this question on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/   Also, I recommend that you draw a circuit diagram and ask for a quick review.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single throw relay (one for each circuit). Your motors each draw more than 7A on startup so you probably want a 20A,230V relay. If your control voltage is 3.3V then look for a NOYITO 30A Relay Module with a High Low Level Trigger (there is a jumper you set for the control voltage).

Note that one of the lines to the pump will always be live - you switch one and avoid the other one.